# How to set an image texture via file location in Unreal?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5, unreal-umg

I'm using **Unreal engine** for a personal project, but am running into a problem.
I want it so that when you click the button in the center of the screen, the brush from the child image changes. I'd use a "select" node, but I've got thousands of images, so I'd rather feed the code a file location since that would be cleaner and less time consuming. I'm not a complete newby to Unreal, I know how to use visual coding to get the desired file location and turn it into a string. But I haven't got a clue of how to use that string to set the texture of an image.

If there are any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The [Get Asset by Object Path](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/AssetRegistry/GetAssetbyObjectPath_Message/) node does exactly what you need.

Have a look at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/s3nlub/get_texture_by_asset_path_and_set_it_as_widget/) Reddit thread for an example of using this node to retrieve a Texture2D object.